# pdcurses installation on Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, gcc, pdcurses

I have some troubles in installing this lib.
My settings is:

```
Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows
```

I download [pdc34dllw.zip](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_pdcurses/downloads/pdcurses/3.4/pdc34dllw.zip/) and I extracted all into a new Eclipse C/C++ project.
So in my project I have:

```
main.cpp
panel.c
curses.h
pdcurses.dll
pdcurses.lib
```

Setting Eclipse Project:

```
GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}"
GCC C Compiler -> Includes  -> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}"
MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries (-l) -> pdcurses
MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries search Path (-L) -> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}"
```

main.cpp content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "curses.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    initscr();
    wclear(stdscr);
    printw("hello world\n");
    wrefresh(stdscr);
    system("pause");
    endwin();

    return(0);
}
```

Error when i try to compile:

> Cannot find -pdcurses

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a day I found a solution to my problem.
Here we are:

Setting:

```
Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
MinGW-w64
```

**Solution:**

1. Go to [Download PdCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/3.4/pdcurs34.zip/download)
2. Extract It in `C:\` (or somewhere)
3. Open Prompt and write `cd C:\Pdcurs34` (if you put the extracted dir in C:)
4. Then `cd win32`
5. If you use MinGW write

   `mingw32-make -f mingwin32.mak WIDE=Y UTF8=Y DLL=Y`
6. Go to Eclipse and create new project
7. Right click on the project and go to properties
8. Go to `C/C++ Build` on the left menu
9. Go to `Settings` and select `Tool Settings` tab
10. In `GCC C++ Compiler` -> `Includes` -> `Include paths (-l)` put `"C:\pdcurs34"`
11. In `GCC C Compiler` -> `Includes` -> `Include paths (-l)` put `"C:\pdcurs34"`
12. In `MinGW C++ Linker` -> `Libraries (-l)` put `pdcurses`
13. In `MinGW C++ Linker` -> `Library search path (-L)` put `C:\pdcurs34\win32`
14. Click ok and close project properties
15. Create main.cpp
16. Paste the code I write below this list
17. Build project
18. You can't use the Eclipse console to see pdcurses output (you can't run your program from Eclipse), so open again Windows Prompt and go into your project directory, then write `cd Debug`
19. write `cp C:\pdcurs34\win32\pdcurses.dll your_project_directory\Debug`
20. run from the Prompt (or click the project `.exe`) your `project_name.exe`

Everything should be fine. Remember always to have a `pdcurses.dll` file inside the `Debug` directory of your project.
For me this worked, I hope it will be the same for you.

**Sample code for test:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();            /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```